# How to display acf repeater in tag archive page?

Tags: taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I want to show some repeater fields on tag archive page.
with this code I can display the simple text fields of acf:

```
$term = get_queried_object();
$meta = get_field('test', $term);
```

but when want to output the acf repeater have no success.

```
$term = get_queried_object();
if (have_rows('faq', $term)) :
    while (have_rows('faq', $term)) : the_row();
        echo get_sub_field('question');
        echo get_sub_field('answer');
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Repeaters are a premium feature I think, so hopefully you can ask ACF support directly?

Comment: When you say you have no success, what exactly is happening? I guess $term is the correct object, that does have a faq meta field? Are you getting false from have_rows even though you do have a value for faq? Is it definitely a repeater / multivalued field? Can you try debugging ACF's have_rows for the value you have to see why it's rejecting it? Or is that returning true, and you're having issues with the_row?

Comment: actually when call the:

`$fields = get_field("faq");
var_dump($fields);`

it returns "null"

or when:

`$term1 = get_queried_object();
$fields = get_field("faq", $term);
var_dump($fields);`

it returns the count of added repeater items not values.